# Async in custom google maps not work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, asynchronous

I have a problem, when I using this code in custom maps from my server (below is example from google documentation, but my script is similar excluding the path to the map). Async loading not work for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Image map types</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script>
var moonTypeOptions = {
  getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
      var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
      if (!normalizedCoord) {
        return null;
      }
      var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
      return 'http://mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw' +
          '/' + zoom + '/' + normalizedCoord.x + '/' +
          (bound - normalizedCoord.y - 1) + '.jpg';
  },
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  maxZoom: 9,
  minZoom: 0,
  radius: 1738000,
  name: 'Moon'
};

var moonMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(moonTypeOptions);

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 1,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['moon']
    }
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  map.mapTypes.set('moon', moonMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('moon');
}

// Normalizes the coords that tiles repeat across the x axis (horizontally)
// like the standard Google map tiles.
function getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom) {
  var y = coord.y;
  var x = coord.x;

  // tile range in one direction range is dependent on zoom level
  // 0 = 1 tile, 1 = 2 tiles, 2 = 4 tiles, 3 = 8 tiles, etc
  var tileRange = 1 << zoom;

  // don't repeat across y-axis (vertically)
  if (y < 0 || y >= tileRange) {
    return null;
  }

  // repeat across x-axis
  if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
    x = (x % tileRange + tileRange) % tileRange;
  }

  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&' +
      'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;

      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My site is blank and console show me:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

But when I using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Image map types</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script>
function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&' +
      'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript; 

var moonTypeOptions = {
  getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
      var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
      if (!normalizedCoord) {
        return null;
      }
      var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
      return 'http://mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw' +
          '/' + zoom + '/' + normalizedCoord.x + '/' +
          (bound - normalizedCoord.y - 1) + '.jpg';
  },
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  maxZoom: 9,
  minZoom: 0,
  radius: 1738000,
  name: 'Moon'
};

var moonMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(moonTypeOptions);

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 1,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['moon']
    }
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  map.mapTypes.set('moon', moonMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('moon');
}

// Normalizes the coords that tiles repeat across the x axis (horizontally)
// like the standard Google map tiles.
function getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom) {
  var y = coord.y;
  var x = coord.x;

  // tile range in one direction range is dependent on zoom level
  // 0 = 1 tile, 1 = 2 tiles, 2 = 4 tiles, 3 = 8 tiles, etc
  var tileRange = 1 << zoom;

  // don't repeat across y-axis (vertically)
  if (y < 0 || y >= tileRange) {
    return null;
  }

  // repeat across x-axis
  if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
    x = (x % tileRange + tileRange) % tileRange;
  }

  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Google maps are loaded on the page, but still shows me:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Any occurence of `google` in global scope(outside of a function) will force this error. The first time you may access `google` is in `initialize`.